# Xcode 5 dp crashes when typing any code

Tags: crash, xcode5

Initially I thought it was Apple's fault. My Xcode 5 dp crashes every time when I tried to type any code.

[image: Xcode crashes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Launch Terminal
2. `cd  ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/`
3. `cd  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Third-Party\ Plug-ins/`
4. Rename/Delete your Plug-ins one by one until XCode 5 works.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 5 go to **Preferences** > **Source Control** > Uncheck the **Enable Source control**

Answer (score 3):

This problem has something to do with auto completion. I remembered I installed a plugin [KSImageNamed](https://github.com/ksuther/KSImageNamed-Xcode). It will auto complete your image name when typing `-[UIImage imageNamed:]`. And most importantly, I saw its name in crash report.

Solution: Go to `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode` and delete `KSImageNamed.xcplugin`.

[image: Delete KSImageNamed]

Answer (score 0):

Great Post. For my case, it is another type of xcode plugin name called "lin" which will do the similar thing. After the plugin is moved to trash, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you should also remove any plug-ins that are located at ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/
If all fails, you might have to uninstall Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. If you go to XCode -> Preferences -> Source Control and turn OFF Source Control everything works like a charm and there are no more crashes!!! :) Hope this help ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in user defined code snippets, located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets. Two different snippets had same Completion Shortcut.